# Python 3: save RAM memory on many small objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, memory, struct

I'm working on an application that creates tens of thousands small Python objects at runtime. Unfortunately, Python objects are notorious for eating a lot of RAM. I found this interesting article on how to tackle that issue:

http://www.qtrac.eu/pysavemem.html

The article gives a few helpful tricks, but doesn't explain them completely. I can't wrap my head around some of the proposed solutions. Please help me to gain insight. We'll walk through them one-by-one.

### 1. Without optimizations

The baseline example from the article is the simple `Rect` class:

```
class Rect:

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
```

On a 64-bit machine running 64-bit Python 3, this object would consume 400KB.

### 2. The __slots__ technique

The `__slots__` technique is by far the easiest optimization. Here is the example from the article:

```
class Rect:
    __slots__ = ("x1", "x2", "y1", "y2")

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y1 = y1
        self.y2 = y2
```

One has to declare the object's attributes `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` beforehand. You can't add arbitrary extra data to the objects created from this class.
The instances will only consume 212KB RAM. That's almost 50% reduction in memory size.

### 3. The 'single Python object' technique

The `Rect()` instances so far would spawn four internal objects each: for `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2`. The new technique that follows attempts to do differently. Instead of four objects, only a *single* Python object gets created:

```
class Rect:
    __slots__ = ("_data",)

    # We are not limited to using the same types; could mix any
    # fixed-width types we want. And, of course, we can add extra
    # items to the struct later if need be.
    Coords = struct.Struct("llll")

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self._data = Rect.Coords.pack(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    @property
    def x1(self):
        return Rect.Coords.unpack(self._data)[0]

    @property
    def x2(self):
        return Rect.Coords.unpack(self._data)[1]

    @property
    def y1(self):
        return Rect.Coords.unpack(self._data)[2]

    @property
    def y2(self):
        return Rect.Coords.unpack(self._data)[3]
```

The article states that the consumed memory is now only 137KB. However, it doesn't explain how. I can't wrap my head around some of the expressions:

- What does `__slots__ = ("_data",)` actually do?
- `Coords` is a class member, not an instance member. So how do you get different data for each instance this way?
- What do those `pack()` and `unpack()` methods actually do?
- The argument of `"llll"` of `Struct()`, does it mean that `x1`, `x2`, `y1` and `y2` are of type `long`?
- The article says that the example could be extended to have writable properties as well. How would that look?

### 4. The 'single Python object' technique (shortened code)

At last, the article gives a similar solution, but with shorter code:

```
def _make_unpacker(index):
    return lambda self: operator.itemgetter(index)(
        Rect.Coords.unpack(self._data))

class Rect:
    __slots__ = ("_data",)

    Coords = struct.Struct("llll")

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self._data = Rect.Coords.pack(x1, y1, x2, y2)

    x1 = property(_make_unpacker(0))
    x2 = property(_make_unpacker(1))
    y1 = property(_make_unpacker(2))
    y2 = property(_make_unpacker(3))
```

This solution is even more unclear to me how it works...

---

Your efforts to explain these optimization techniques will be greatly appreciated! Feel free to propose other solutions if applicable. Personally, I use the latest Python 3.7 release.

Answer (score 1):

There is yet another approach based of [recordclass](https://pypi.org/project/recordclass) library:

```
from recordclass import dataobject

class Rectangle(dataobject):
    x1:int
    x2:int
    y1:int
    y2:int
```

This solution has require less memory than `__slots__`-based one. The difference is equal to the size of `PyGC_Head` (24 bytes on 64-bit platform, 16 bytes on Python >= 3.9). It also may have faster instance creation path than `__slots__` based solution:

```
class Rectangle(dataobject):
    x1:int
    x2:int
    y1:int
    y2:int
    __options__ = {'fast_new':True}
```

Since recordclass 0.15:

```
class Rectangle(dataobject, fast_new=True):
    x1:int
    x2:int
    y1:int
    y2:int
```

Comment: Are you the author of `recordclass`? Looks like the repo for `recordclass` is no longer available?

Comment: Repo on bitbucket is not available. I moved the repository to github.com/intellimath/recordclass. Now it is the main repository of the library. The information about source location on PyPI will be updated starting from version 0.20.1.